# sortrows in the 2nd dimension of 3d matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort first row in the 2nd dimension of a 3d matrix in Matlab, but sortrows() doesn't work in this case.

For example, I have a matrix like

```
a(:,:,1)
1 2 4
3 1 6
2 0 5

a(:,:,2)
3 5 6
1 2 4
0 2 2
```

and I need to get the result

```
a(:,:,1)
1 2 4
2 0 5
3 1 6

a(:,:,2)
0 2 2
1 2 4
3 5 6
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to *sort* **rows** within *each* third-dim **slice** according to the value of the *first* **column**.

```
[m,n,p] = size(a);
[~, row_ind] = sort(a(:,1,:), 1);
lin_ind = bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@plus, row_ind, (0:n-1)*m), reshape((0:p-1)*m*n, 1, 1, p));
result = a(lin_ind);
```

**How this works**:

Sort `a(:,1:,)` along the first dimension (rows), and get the indices of the sorting (using the second output of [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html); line 2). From those row indices, generate the [linear indices](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) (using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); line 3) that will give the desired result (line 4).

**Example**:

For input

```
a(:,:,1) = [1 2 4
            3 1 6
            2 0 5];
a(:,:,2) = [3 5 6
            1 2 4
            0 2 2];
```

this produces

```
result(:,:,1) =
     1     2     4
     2     0     5
     3     1     6
result(:,:,2) =
     0     2     2
     1     2     4
     3     5     6
```

Comment: This should be the perfect solution. beautiful :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sortrows` with each 2d matrix:

```
a(:,:,1)=sortrows(a(:,:,1));
a(:,:,2)=sortrows(a(:,:,2));
```

Of course you can do it in a loop